# Is it possible to load an extension from PHP cli interface, without modify the ini file?

Tags: php

I checked `man php` and output of `php -h`, but I didn't seem to find such thing.

But I remember seeing it somewhere, you could do something like `php -Xabc.so script.php` to load an extension temporarily.

Anyone know that?

Comment: why this approach vs the 'regular' way ?

Comment: @Dagon: it often doesn't make sense to load some exotic module for all the scripts if it's only required by one of them. So perhaps it's easier to load it explicitly

Comment: are they not loaded once on boot, so no real overhead?

Comment: @Dagon In the case of preforked workers, you'll notice this in memory usage.

Comment: @Dagon: in CLI there is no "once on boot" events. Everything is loaded as long as you run the command

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Loading a regular extension via CLI is done with:

```
php -dextension=abc.so myfile.php
```

If your extension is not in the default path you can provide an absolute path as well:

```
php -dextension=/path/to/abc.so myfile.php
```

To load a Zend extension, it'd advisable to always pass an absolute path:

```
php -dzend_extension=/path/to/abc.so myfile.php
```

Comment: Oh, forgotten that "zend extension" is a different extension type :-S +1

Comment: Hmm, I still have to copy that so to `/usr/lib/php/modules/`, anyway to avoid copying?

Comment: @warl0ck You should be able to give an absolute path as well, i.e. `-dextension=/path/to/extension.so`.

Comment: Since xdebug might be one of the most important use cases, here is the example line to use it `php -dzend_extension=xdebug.so vendor/bin/phpunit` Hope it helps.

Comment: @Trendfischer generally speaking, you would want to disable xdebug when running phpunit, not enable it....so I either misunderstood what you're doing or this is not a popular use-case at all..

Comment: @Christian Certainly it is, you should not enable xdebug for every day testing, but sometimes on developing further tests you'll need a code coverage and for this xdebug is required. And that's why a command line like this is very helpful.

Comment: OK, I see...you're "whitelisting" instead of "blacklisting". It is arguably a better approach.

Comment: @Ja͢ck How to find default path for CLI?

Comment: @Ja͢ck Does it load once or add it in php.ini file? When I ran the command it didnt show command prompt again,as if some script is running

Comment: Excellent solution

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

```
 -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.
```

Found it by googling for "php cli load extension"

Comment: `modules/abc.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension`, so I guess a zend extension is not a php extension?

Comment: @warl0ck: that depends. Some extensions are Zend extensions, like xdebug

Answer (score 0):

To disable all by default (by ignoring `php.ini`) and specify specific PHP extensions, try:

```
php -n $(for e in curl ctype json iconv; { echo -dextension=$e.so; } | xargs) -m
```

To run the script, change `-m` into file name.