# Should how I write PHP and PHPUnit command?

Tags: php, phpunit

As my **phpunit** file `test/a.php` needs to use the **PHP** extension `A.so`, I write the following command:

```
php -d extension=A.so -d max_execution_time=100 /usr/local/bin/phpunit -v --debug test/
```

When I run the command and it will output the following info:

> /usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off   /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/5.4.6/libexec/phpunit-5.4.6.phar "$@"

Why does it not run the phpunit code?

If I add `extension=A.so` to `php.ini` file and run **phpunit** file, it will be OK.

So, I want to combine the php command and the **phpunit** command.

Comment: Just a guess, as you have a command inside another command, put the inner command in quotes: `php -d extension=A.so -d max_execution_time=100 "/usr/local/bin/phpunit -v --debug test/"`

Comment: @DanFromGermany That won't work, as php will try to run a script with name _`/usr/local/bin/phpunit -v --debug test/`_

Comment: Where is this extention A.so located? If it's not in a standard directory, then you'll need to specify the directory of where it's located.

Comment: ^^ See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811482/is-it-possible-to-load-an-extension-from-php-cli-interface-without-modify-the-i#12811521